# Reading busy bit of 1602A LCD

Tags: arduino, lcd, character-lcd

I made a toy program on Arduino to write "Hello, World!" to the display using delays after every command.

Now I was wondering if I could get rid of the delays if I read the busy bit.

This is the current program:

```
enum pins {
    RS,
    RW,
    E,
    D0,
    D1,
    D2,
    D3,
    D4,
    D5,
    D6,
    D7
};

const int NPINS = 11;
int busy = 1;

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NPINS; i++)
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

    // clear display
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    pin_send();
    delay(2);

    // function set (8 bit mode)
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    pin_send();
    delayMicroseconds(37);

    // display on
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0);
    pin_send();
    delayMicroseconds(37);
    
    // entry mode
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
    pin_send();
    delayMicroseconds(37);

    // write data
    pin_set(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0); // H
    pin_send();
    delayMicroseconds(37);

    /* this keeps going */
}

void pin_set(int rs, int rw, int d7, int d6, int d5, int d4, int d3, int d2, int d1, int d0) {
    digitalWrite(RS, rs);
    digitalWrite(RW, rw);
    digitalWrite(D7, d7);
    digitalWrite(D6, d6);
    digitalWrite(D5, d5);
    digitalWrite(D4, d4);
    digitalWrite(D3, d3);
    digitalWrite(D2, d2);
    digitalWrite(D1, d1);
    digitalWrite(D0, d0);
}

void pin_send() {
    digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(E, LOW);
}
```

As a test I tried to replace the first delay with this function that waits for the busy bit to be 0:

```
void waitFree() {
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // reset pins

    for (int i = D0; i < NPINS; i++) // set all data pins to input mode
        pinMode(i, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(RW, HIGH); // set read/write pin to read
    pin_send();

    while(busy)
        busy = isBusy();

    digitalWrite(RW, LOW); // set read/write pin to write

    for (int i = D0; i < NPINS; i++) // set all data pins to output mode
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

}

int isBusy() {
    return digitalRead(D7);
}
```

But this outputs 1 every time I read pin D7. I'm very new to this and I'm lost to what I might be doing wrong.

EDIT:

I changed the function to set the E pin high instead of pulsing high and low but I still get 1 when I read pin D7.

```
void waitFree() {
    pin_set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // reset pins

    for (int i = D0; i < NPINS; i++) // set all data pins to input mode
        pinMode(i, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(RW, HIGH); // set read/write pin to read
    digitalWrite(E, HIGH); // <--- EDITED

    while(busy)
        busy = isBusy();

    digitalWrite(E, LOW); // <--- EDITED
    digitalWrite(RW, LOW); // set read/write pin to write

    for (int i = D0; i < NPINS; i++) // set all data pins to output mode
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);

}
```

Comment: The qapass is not the LCD name. It is a sticker that says Quality Assurance Passed.

Comment: Oh! I feel stupid. Thanks, I'll edit it !

Answer (score 0):

The pin D7 must be read while E is high, so the LCD is actually driving the bus.

Now the code just pulses E high and low, and LCD is not driving the bus, so reading D7 will only read high because of the internal LCD pull-ups.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I made a change to the code so I set E high only once but I keep receiving 1s when I read pin D7. I edited the post with the code.

Comment: That is also how it is not meant to work. Set E high, read D7, set E low. And your busy variable is global, so if the LCD says it is ready, your code never reads D7 again and assumes it is always ready.

Comment: do you men in this way ?
`while(busy) {
    digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
    busy = isBusy();
    digitalWrite(E, LOW);
}`

Comment: Yes, with a suitable delay after setting E high, before reading D7, and suitable delay after setting E low. The delay should be about 500ns to 2000ns, depending on what LCD controller and supply voltage you use. The E pulses can't be too short and can't happen too often.

Comment: I still get only 1s even with a 10ms delay.

Comment: any idea what might be happening there ?